# Sequelize Parens in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sequelize.js, where-clause

I have a WHERE clause that looks like this.

```
WHERE (`version` = FALSE
       OR (name LIKE '%8%')
       OR (name LIKE '%9%')
       AND (sId IN (1)))
```

I need it to look like this.

```
WHERE (`version` = FALSE
       OR (name LIKE '%8%')
       OR (name LIKE '%9%'))
       AND (sId IN (1))
```

I'm using where.push and I can't seem to figure it out.

Sequelize code.

```
where.push(version: false)
where.push(Sequelize.literal(`OR (name LIKE '%${id1}%')`)
where.push(Sequelize.literal(`OR (name LIKE '%${id2}%')`)
where.push({sId: {$in: sIds}})
```

Comment: share your sequelize code

Comment: If all else fails you could just execute a raw query. See https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Sequelize.literal` (and definitely don't try to compose such conditions yourself in a string to avoid SQL injections) if you can write such conditions using some `Op` operators.
In your case you can use `Op.or` and `Op.like` operators:

```js
where = {
  [Op.or]: [{
    version: false,
  }, {
    name: {
      [Op.like]: `%${id1}%`
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      [Op.like]: `%${id2}%`
    }
  },
  ],
  sId: {
   [Op.in]: sIds
  }
}
```